# Z-Index in card-panel of Materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, materialize

I've two images inside a [Card Panel](http://materializecss.com/cards.html) and I wanted to show them as one exactly on top of another, using Z-Index. I want the image to be re-sized by it's parent container (Card Panel) so did non hard-code its width & height. With the following code, I'm getting the overlapping effect and also images are getting re-sized properly but the overlapped image is appearing outside the Card's boundary (vertically). Card Panel (in white color) is not considering the image height.

HTML:

```
<div class="col s6 m4 l2">
 <div class="card-panel">
  <div class="container">
   <img id="back" src="/image/back.png">
   <img id="front" src="/image/front.png">
  </div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
 position: relative;
}
.container img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
.container #back {
 z-index: 1;
}
.container #front {
 z-index: 2;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting `#back` to `-1`

Comment: Thanks but it don't re-size the Card Panel either

Comment: It would be more helpful if we could see your actual output. If you can post it in jsfiddle or a relevant example. (Or a snippet on here.)

Comment: Hi Tom, in pic the #back img is the girl and there is a 1x1 px transparent image in #front

Comment: Are you intending for the image to appear in front of the text? If not, then you should just set it as a background image for your panel. If so, then you can just set the image as a background for the overlay. You can also set the height of the overlay div and use the object-fit property to adjust how the image is displayed (for example, using `cover`).

Comment: Thanks Tom, I want the image to appear first, followed by the text. Back image is to fallback on if the front is not available. Could you send some code, I tried with background-image but could not re-size it so moved to z-index, I've the last option to calculate the height and set it using JQuery, but that's a last resort.

Comment: Also I think, if the front image is 1x1 pixel then the background-image will also be 1x1 pixel.

Answer (score 1):

May you set the element with id #back z-index -1

```
#back{ z-index: -1; }
```